# Google Maps API using urllib.request cannot save jpg file

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, gis, urllib

I am using Google Maps API, static map, and would like to save an image file in format JPG.

When I am saving a PNG using `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'map_46_6.png')` this is working fine. However, when I am using `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'map_46_6.jpg')`, this is not working. Opening the file gives an error « Not a JPG file: starts with 0x89 0x50 ». Changing manually the extension to PNG will resolve it.

The following is the code :

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&center=46.257632,6.108669&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=xxxxx'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'map_46_6.jpg')
```

As this code is part of a previously built pipeline, I would need the JPG files for the next steps.

My question is, is there a setting in Urllib, Google Maps or anything else that could result in this error? Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. If one wants jpg, one needs to explicitly code the format, `&format=jpg` like the following:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&center=46.257632,6.108669&zoom=16&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&format=jpg&key=xxxx'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'map_46_6.jpg')
```